# Flutter change Textstyle

Tags: flutter

I have a list and when I press the checkbox, I need the text to be stroken.

This is my method for checking the checkbox.
Any idea how I can implement the change of new textStyle here?

my method:

```
void toggleDone(TodoTask task, bool newValue) {
    print("Status before processing");

    task.status = newValue;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to change sth depending on the state you can do it like that with tenary operator:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool change = false;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      change = !change;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              style: TextStyle(color: change ? Colors.red :Colors.black87),
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example text color will change when u click the button. So you need to change this 'control variable' inside your function and widget will rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextDecoration.lineThrough property of TextStyle to put a line through or strike through text. There are several examples of how to use [TextStyle in Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html). The code shows how to change the TextStyle when Checkbox value is changed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _value = false;

  //void toggleDone(TodoTask task, bool newValue) {
  void toggleDone(bool newValue) {
    print("Status before processing");

    _value = newValue;
    //task.status = newValue;
    //notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Flutter Demo Home Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Checkbox(
                value: _value,
                onChanged: (val) => setState(() => toggleDone(val))),
            Text('TextDecoration LineThrough Demo',
                style: _value
                    ? TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough, fontSize: 25)
                    : TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```